# Inter-board connect using DIN41612

Tags: prototyping

I am using a Double Eurocard PCB prototyping board from Multicomp pro, (See https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3216080.pdf) to build a pet project - it's wire-wrapped.  I would like to be able to connect this board to another board of the same type. According to that datasheet, I can add a 64-way DIN41612 Socket to the board, and I have found some on RS that have wire-wrap Pins.
My problem is that I can't find a cable that will connect the two boards, using these DIN41612. I realise it's an obsolete standard, and was intended to be used with a backplane.
But I was hoping someone here might know of such a cable, or perhaps have an alternative solution I could try.

Comment: Can you find a more modern connector, or cable assembly with wire wrap pins on 0.1" grid?

Comment: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/din-41612-connectors/0119643

This kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, normally you don't use a cable.  Instead you have a "backplane" which has a PCB with 2 or more of the mating connectors, and interconnect wiring.  The backplane may also provide power, and it may be mounted in a chassis with guide rails and mounting hardware.

Something like this is an example of a [backplane](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/backplanes-motherboards/0435068) , and the same page contains links to eurocard chassis.

*Edit*
For debug purposes (as @DiBosco points out in comments), ribbon cables were commonly used for interconnecting cards instead of PCB backplane.  Have a look for IDC versions of the connectors [IDC DIN41612](https://www.mouser.co.uk/c/connectors/backplane-connectors/din-41612-connectors/?termination%20style=IDC).

Comment: Back in the early 90s where we used 41612 connectors everywhere on motherboard to daughterboard systems, we had 64 way ribbons that you could use for debugging. Whether you can still get these cable mount 41612s...

Comment: Like these https://www.mouser.co.uk/c/connectors/backplane-connectors/din-41612-connectors/?termination%20style=IDC ?

Comment: Them's the ones :)

Comment: Thanks all! Delighted to discover those connectors. Since I should only need 2 boards, that should solve the problem.